# select2 hierarchical data from json

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

Is it possible to have select2 (https://select2.github.io) show a hierarchical show from a json encode?

Here's my json encode that i'd like to use.

```
 var defaultData = 
    [
{
    "category_id": "3",
    "parent_id": "1",
    "text": "PC Onderdelen",
    "is_active": "1",
    "position": "2",
    "level": "1",
    "href": "?id=3",
    "nodes": [
        {
            "category_id": "6",
            "parent_id": "3",
            "text": "Behuizingen",
            "is_active": "1",
            "position": "1",
            "level": "2",
            "tags": [
                "1"
            ],
            "href": "?id=6",
            "nodes": [
                {
                    "category_id": "7",
                    "parent_id": "6",
                    "text": "Midi Tower",
                    "is_active": "1",
                    "position": "1",
                    "level": "3",
                    "tags": [
                        "1"
                    ],
                    "href": "?id=7"
                }
            ]
        }
```

I couldn't find any information about this, so any help is appreciated!

Comment: Replace nodes with children and that should work.

Comment: Thanks, could you also help me with the jquery and php part of this?

Comment: You're going to need to include some php and jquery in your question in order to get help